# Unix Bash script to create index for Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, unix

I'm trying to create a table with an index using a Bash script in the Unix environment. The individual SQL queries are running correctly. The issue is that the index of the table cannot be created.

As shown:

```
    sqlplus -s $CONNECTION   << EOF
    set pages 0 feed off time off timing off

    CREATE TABLE $TABLENAME 
       (    "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
            "USAGE" VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) 
       )         
      TABLESPACE "DB_TABLES" ;

      CREATE INDEX $TABLENAME_IDX1 ON $TABLENAME ("USAGE") 
      TABLESPACE "DB_TABLES" ;
    exit;
    EOF
```

The table will be created without the index.

Added: tried splitting the queries; added '/' behind each; when queries are run in SQL-Developer, it is fine.

Comment: Can you please check if the user that you are using for connecting via Bash Script have privileges required for the creation of Index.

Comment: Hi vish , I have tried running it with the same user in sqldeveloper it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your problem be that you don't have a variable `$TABLENAME_IDX1` but you were hoping to use the table name concatenated with `_IDX1`?  If so, the solution is:

```
CREATE INDEX ${TABLENAME}_IDX1 ON $TABLENAME ("USAGE") 
TABLESPACE "DB_TABLES";
```

The other part of the solution is to run the script with `bash -x yourscript.sh` to see exactly what is executed.  You would probably have spotted this problem if you had done that.

If this is not the correct diagnosis, you should most certainly run your script with `bash -x` to see what is executed.  You might want to show that output, along with the error message(s), in the question.